# How to use table functions

Tags: plsql

I was trying to use tabel functions but after creating this block:

```
create table tmp_ft
(field   VARCHAR2 ( 1000 ));

DECLARE

 TYPE names_nt IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 ( 1000 );

 FUNCTION lotsa_names (  
   base_name_in   IN   VARCHAR2  
 , count_in       IN   INTEGER  
)  
   RETURN names_nt  
IS  
   retval names_nt := names_nt ( );  
BEGIN  
   retval.EXTEND ( count_in );  

   FOR indx IN 1 .. count_in  
   LOOP  
      retval ( indx ) := base_name_in || ' ' || indx;  
   END LOOP;  

   RETURN retval;  
END lotsa_names; 

BEGIN

 insert into tmp_ft
 SELECT *
 FROM TABLE ( lotsa_names ( 'Steven', 5 )) ;

END;
/
```

I get the following error:

```
ORA-06550: line 26, column 15:
PLS-00231: function 'LOTSA_NAMES' may not be used in SQL
```

Why? It seems all is ok but I can't understand why it doesn't work

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because the function and the type you are using are defines locally to the anonymous block. Thus they cannot be used outside of that block. In Oracle there are separate engines for SQL and PLSQL. So any SQL actually runs outside the block. You need to define the type and function at the schema level.

```
create table tmp_ft
(field   VARCHAR2 ( 1000 ));

create  type names_nt is table of varchar2 ( 1000 );

create or replace
 function lotsa_names (  
   base_name_in   in   varchar2  
 , count_in       in   integer  
)  
   return names_nt  
is  
   retval names_nt := names_nt ( );  
begin  
   retval.extend ( count_in );  

   for indx in 1 .. count_in  
   loop  
      retval ( indx ) := base_name_in || ' ' || indx;  
   end loop;  

   return retval;  
end lotsa_names;
```

--======= Test =========

```
begin    
 insert into tmp_ft
 select *
   from table ( lotsa_names ( 'Steven', 5 )) ;    
end;

select * from tmp_ft;
```

Comment: If the above solved your issue then please accept the answer. If not then what is the remaining issue. Please don't just leave the question unanswered.